# Dynamically attached event handler not working with Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a checkbox inside a update panel. Based on certain conditions, I set the autopostback property to true and also attach a event handler as below

```
chkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.ChkBoxChaned_Click);
```

But when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, autopostback happens but the event handler does not get hit.

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you attaching the event handler?  If it's not in Init or Load, that's a problem.